# Why exactly does a scarf help against a neck pain and a sore throat?

Tags: human-biology, medicine

I was going out without a scarf and as this day my neck
was more sensitive; after a while my voice was
rasping, I needed to cough and my neck was hurting
slightly.

After coming home I put on my silk scarf and the effect
was almost immediate. The pain cedes and my voiced normalized.
Why exactly is the warmth provided by a scarf so quick and
effective for our neck ? I can see that isolating the neck
is more effective than a warm room (air is a bad heat conductor),
but why does the warmth help us to combat rasping and coughing ?
What causes rasping and coughing by the way ?

Comment: It is not like this for everyone by any means; why it is for you is a bit of a different question. Also, there'smore than one question there. The *by the way* has a long, separate answer.

Comment: Placebo Effect.